# Make the script better. The smoke is not smoothing enough

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have created a script to animate smoke. I animate three png files. These png files are files with smoke images.

But sometimes the script is a bit choppy and the smoke animation is not smooth. Sometimes when reloading the Smoke the animation is not smooth.

How can I fix the problem so that the smoke animation runs smoothly.

You can see the script and demo on jsfiddle (editable):

[The script on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EeWEL/1/)

Comment: do you see choppiness in all browsers or in a browser in particular? I don't see choppiness on Firefox 7, Linux.

Comment: I like the effect.  I only saw a choppiness once, but it was very brief.  Is there a reason you don't just overlay an animated gif?

Comment: @rkw: a gif would only allow binary transparency, which would definitely look worse.

Comment: you can:0. it looks great :) 1. create all your divs only once at the beginning and reuse them; 2. detach current div instead of removing it; 3. cache your smoke element;

Comment: @Irishka: I tried caching his smoke element; it did not resolve the occasional animation hiccup.

Comment: I only saw some choppiness when the smoke sprites were loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very cool.

Using `transform` (`-webkit-transform`, `-moz-transform`, and `-o-transform`) to animate the movement instead of absolute positioning by `bottom` will get most browsers to kick in hardware acceleration, that should take care of the flickering.

I don't know about IE though...